# Hive - Can one extract common options for reuse in other scripts?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hive-configuration

I have two Hive scripts which look like this:

Script A:

> ```
> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict;
> SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
>
> ... do something ...
> ```

Script B:

> ```
>   SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
>   SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict;
>   SET hive.exec.parallel=true;
>
> ... do something else ...
> ```

The options that we set at the beginning of each script are the same. Is it possible somehow to extract them out to a common place (for example, into a commonoptions.sql) so that our scripts look like this:

Script A:

> ```
>  <run commonoptions.sql>
>
> ... do something ...
> ```

Script B:

> ```
>  <run commonoptions.sql>
>
> ... do something else ...
> ```

Ideally I would like to extract out table defintions as well, so that I have:

Script A:

> ```
>  <run commonoptions.sql>
>  <run defineExternalTableXYZ.sql>
> ... do something with Table XYZ ...
> ```

Script B:

> ```
>  <run commonoptions.sql>
>  <run defineExternalTableXYZ.sql>
> ... do something else with Table XYZ ...
> ```

That way I can manage the TableXYZ definition at a single spot. I am not using the Hive CLI. I am using Amazon EMR with Hive Steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can store these configuration parameters in common file and load in each of your scripts using `source` command:

```
source /tmp/common_init.hql;
```

Also you can generate this file for each workflow from the database.

Comment: I clarified the question. I am not using the CLI, so source is not an option for me.

Comment: You have your scripts stored in S3 right? In this case you can use the `cat` command to concatenate your scripts with common parameters and then execute concatenated script.

Comment: So you mean to say I should run a cat command to combine the two files and then upload/sync the files via aws cli before running the hive job? That can actually work. So something like this: cat commonOptions.sql script1_base.sql > script1.sql;  aws s3 sync script1.sql <s3 path>; <run hive step>. Did I get the gist of your solution correctly?

Comment: Yes I mean the same. Remember about eventual consistency in S3... If you will create each time unique file name (using date as suffix) - it's safer than re-creating the same file. I'm not sure, maybe eventual consistency is not an issue for your case

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `hive -i config.hql -f script_A.hql`, where `config.hql` would contain your dynamic settings.  The `-i` flag allows you to pass an initialization script that will be executed before the actual hive file passed to `-f`.  I'm not super familiar with how AWS kicks off hive jobs in steps, but presumably you edit the submission arguments.