# How can I gain more composability / reusability in my Hive SQL scripts?

Tags: sql, hive, reusability

I'm developing several Hive-based ETLs, and have seriously violated the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

How can I gain more composability / reusability in my Hive SQL scripts?

Basically I'm looking for an `INCLUDE` or `IMPORT` command.

Any tips?  For folks that write a ton of HiveQL scripts, how do you not repeat yourself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40783621/2700344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have your reusable hive script into small `.HQL` files. Create shell script for ordered execution of the `.HQL` files.

All you need to make sure that the current executing script do have its pre-requisite completed. i.e. it should have expected table/schema.

There are two things, which would help you.

1) the `hive -f abcd.hql` command : Use a series of this command in the shell script for ordered execution of the scripts. e.g.

```
hive -f specific.hql
wait $! 
hive -f reusable1.hql
wait $! 
hive -f specific2.hql
wait $! 
hive -f specific3.hql
wait $! 
hive -f reusable2.hql
```

You might note the `wait` commands, basically to tell the shell to wait for last command to complete. This is very important when output table of the last script is input to the next one.

2) Use `hiveconf` to customize table, schema (or even where conditions or column names) at runtime. e.g. `create table '${hiveconf:schema.name}.my_table ...`